# R rugarch simulation

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I'd like to know the range of each parameter in the rugarch specification models.
For example for distribution error "nig" and model "apARCH". I'd like to know what is the range for the parameters "skew", "shape" related to the "nig" distribution and the parameters "gamma" and "delta" for the model "apARCH".
This is my code example:

```
varianceModel = list(model="apARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1))
meanModel = list(armaOrder=c(1,1))
distributionModel = "nig"
fixedPars = list(mu=0, ar1 = 0.1, ma1= 0.9, omega=0.001, alpha1=0.1, beta1=0.8, gamma1 = 0.01, delta = 2, shape=1.5, skew = 0.2)


spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = varianceModel, 
                         mean.model= meanModel, distribution.model=distributionModel, 
                         fixed.pars=fixedPars)
path.sgarch <- ugarchpath(spec, n.sim=1000, n.start=1, m.sim=20)
```

Now for each of this parameters, how I can get the possible range or the "standard" parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by range? A range of values that can be assigned to, e.g., `skew`?

Comment: yes, the possible values for each parameters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a list of ranges of possible values of such parameters in the documentation of `rugarch`, while [this introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) provides only some partial information.

Those ranges of possible values, however, are (at least should be) standard in the sense that they provide well-defined distributions and stationary models. Hence, you should be able to find all such ranges in some other sources.

However, regarding the distributions, there actually is a hidden source in `rugarch` that you can use---the `rugarch:::.DistributionBounds` function source code. For instance, it contains

```
if (distribution == "nig") {
    skew = 0.2
    skew.LB = -0.99
    skew.UB = 0.99
    shape = 0.4
    shape.LB = 0.01
    shape.UB = 25
}
```

meaning that the lower and upper bounds for `skew` are -0.99 and 0.99, respectively. To extract those numbers faster, you may use

```
rugarch:::.DistributionBounds("nig")[c("skew.LB", "skew.UB")]
# $skew.LB
# [1] -0.99
#
# $skew.UB
# [1] 0.99
```

Regarding the variance models, typically "simple" ranges, such as as -1 < gamma < 1 for [APARCH](https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc/5?topic=mdls), are not available/what you want, because they only allow the model to exist, but doesn't guarantee stationarity. For instance, for GARCH(1,1) to be stationary we need alpha + beta < 1; hence, we actually have higher dimensional constraints than just intervals. As I said, you may find those online.

However, `ugarchpath` also checks those conditions by computing `persistence(spec)`. Now, as you can see in

```
getMethod("persistence", signature(object = "uGARCHspec", pars = "missing", 
                                   distribution = "missing", model = "missing", 
                                   submodel="missing"))
```

there is a different way to compute this persistence for each specification. For instance, for APARCH we look at

```
rugarch:::.persistaparch1
# function (pars, idx, distribution = "norm") 
# {
#     alpha = pars[idx["alpha", 1]:idx["alpha", 2]]
#     beta = pars[idx["beta", 1]:idx["beta", 2]]
#     gamma = pars[idx["gamma", 1]:idx["gamma", 2]]
#     delta = pars[idx["delta", 1]:idx["delta", 2]]
#     skew = pars[idx["skew", 1]:idx["skew", 2]]
#     shape = pars[idx["shape", 1]:idx["shape", 2]]
#     ghlambda = pars[idx["ghlambda", 1]:idx["ghlambda", 2]]
#     ps = sum(beta) + sum(apply(cbind(gamma, alpha), 1, FUN = function(x) x[2] * 
#         aparchKappa(x[1], delta, ghlambda, shape, skew, distribution)))
#     return(ps)
# }
```

and the condition is that `ps < 1`. Notice that

```
rugarch:::.persistsgarch1
# function (pars, idx, distribution = "norm") 
# {
#     ps = sum(pars[idx["alpha", 1]:idx["alpha", 2]]) + sum(pars[idx["beta", 
#         1]:idx["beta", 2]])
#     return(ps)
# }
```

gives exactly alpha + beta in the case of GARCH(1,1) and then `ugarchpath`checks the aforementioned stationarity condition. Hence, the most straightforward thing that you can do is to check if `persistence(spec) < 1` before simulating. For instance, in your example,

```
persistence(spec)
# [1] 0.8997927
```

Comment: Your answer clarify all to me. I didn't know how could I set the parameters. Thank you! :)